# GZIP not enabled when I have code in htaccess for it - How to enable it?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip

I have added the following code to my site (it has been on the site for a while), but any time I check to see if GZIP is enabled on websites that check for it, it always come back not enabled.

I run a dedicated server via Apache.

What could I be doing wrong?

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ##ExpiresDefault A1
    ##Header append Cache-Control must-revalidate
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpg A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/ico A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/ico A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
    ## ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000

    # Add a far future Expires header for fonts
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000

    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
        Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Edit - Addition added

```
<ifmodule deflate_module.c>
    DeflateCompressionLevel 1
    DeflateBufferSize 8096
    DeflateMemLevel 8
    DeflateWindowSize 8

    # compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: I think the mod for gzip is `mod_deflate`. `mod_gzip` seems to be unofficial. Did you verify any of those are enabled?

Comment: @TobiasK Sorry, I forgot to include that part of my code.I have the `deflate_module.c` in my file as well.

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file allowed to override these settings? I think by default it's not and you have to add `AllowOverride All` in your VirtualHost/Apache config.

Comment: @TobiasK My htaccess file works though.